# Pasar varias variables con javascript desde una vista a una funcion en el controlador

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

**Hola amigos de stack overflow en español, mi pregunta es si pueden ayduarme a poder pasar más de una variable en el siguiente código, les estaré muy agradecido**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function PagarCuotaCuenta(cuotas,importe,id_cuentacorriente){

  var cuotas = cuotas;
  var importe = importe;
  var id_cuentacorriente = id_cuentacorriente;

  document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() . 'clientes/C_Cliente/PagarCuentaCorriente/' ?>" + importe;
  
 }
</script>
```

Comment: No, entiendo muy bien tu pregunta. Te refieres a algo así?:
`document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() . 'clientes/C_Cliente/PagarCuentaCorriente/importe'" + importe + "/cuotas"+ cuotas + "/cuentacorriente" + id_cuentacorriente +" ?>";`

Comment: hola muchas gracias por contestar, creo que es lo que estoy buscando, la idea es pasar las 3 variables por url

Comment: no  me toma las comillas en el código que pegaste

Comment: escribí otra respuesta abajo, para que sea mas legible.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer entonces es algo así:

```
var uri = "http://localhost:8080/clientes/C_Cliente/PagarCuentaCorriente.php?cuotas=" + cuotas + "&importe=" + importe + "&cuentacorriente=" + id_cuentacorriente;
window.location.href = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

En lo particular no me gustar usar php en javascript, mejor uso la ruta a mi server, en el ejemplo apunto a mi localhost y los archivos a los que mandaré mi request.

Además uso encodeURIComponent, esta función codifica caracteres especiales.

Y con tu ejemplo, creo que sería algo así:

```
document.location.href = "<?php echo base_url() . 'clientes/C_Cliente/PagarCuentaCorriente.php?cuotas=" + cuotas + "&importe=" + importe + "&cuentacorriente=" + id_cuentacorriente +"'";
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Isaac, fue de gran ayuda!

Comment: Estimado Fede, si este comentario soluciono tu problema, te recomiendo que lo marques como solución, de esta manera ayudas al orden de la comunidad y a Isaac de vuelta 

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para que no te compliques concatenando variables de php con variables javascript,
declara la variable baseurl como una variable javascript y luego la concatenas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PagarCuotaCuenta(cuotas,importe,id_cuentacorriente){
        var baseurl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';
        var cuotas = cuotas;
        var importe = importe;
        var id_cuentacorriente = id_cuentacorriente;

        document.location.href = base_url+'clientes/C_Cliente/PagarCuentaCorriente/' + importe;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: muchas gracias por contestar, fue de gran ayuda tu ejemplo!